# jQuery select list issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code something like

```
    if($('#nodeNo').val() == null){
              cityChange(1);                      
              $('#nodeNo option[value=<%=request.getAttribute("nodeval")%>]').attr('selected','selected');
    }
```

There is an Ajax call in cityChange(1) to populate the nodeNo select list and then the next statement sets the selected value. However due to parallel execution the above code doesn't work. The ajax call and setting the value executes together. The other Ajax call takes a bit time and by that time the next statement finishes execution. Hence the list is populated correctly but the selected value can't be set.

Pls Help!!

Comment: why don't you just put the $('#nodeNo..') inside the callback of the ajax call? that way you don't have to worry about any race conditions

Comment: May is see your ajax methods

Comment: @AkhilKNambiar you should read the jquery docs if you don't know how to do that, but we can help if you show us the ajax call

Comment: @kennypu due to some conditions I can't transfer the set function call to within Ajax i.e. the function cityChange(1). What's the next option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to transfer

```
$('#nodeNo option[value=<%=request.getAttribute("nodeval")%>]').attr('selected','selected');
```

into the ajax success callback inside the `cityChange` method.

Comment: due to some conditions I can't transfer the set function call to within Ajax i.e. the function cityChange(1). What's the next option?

Comment: Just an idea. Define a global variable. Set the variable inside cityChange success callback and use setInterval to check whether that variable is set or not. If set, then select the dropdown list.

Answer (score 1):

You are having ajax call and your setting the data source for that select element in the success or complete of ajax call and i suggest you to set the selected value in ajax complete of   cityChange(1); method.

Regards,

Comment: due to some conditions I can't transfer the set function call to within Ajax i.e. the function cityChange(1). What's the next option?